# react-native run job when app-closed on android

Tags: javascript, react-native

Tried react-native-background-fetch and react-native-background-job both libraries does not run the code when app is closed, followed the documentation clearly

react-native-background-fetch job runs when custom event created using
when app is in foreground
 adb shell cmd jobscheduler run -f com.bg_fetch 999
, also periodic event is not triggered after 15 min(as given in config)

For react-native-background-job job does not run even in background

Tested on android-9

```
componentDidMount() {
    // Configure it.
    BackgroundFetch.configure({
      minimumFetchInterval: 15,     // <-- minutes (15 is minimum allowed)
      // Android options
      stopOnTerminate: false,
      startOnBoot: true,
      requiredNetworkType: BackgroundFetch.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY, // Default
      requiresCharging: false,      // Default
      requiresDeviceIdle: false,    // Default
      requiresBatteryNotLow: false, // Default
      requiresStorageNotLow: false,  // Default
      enableHeadless:true,
    }, async() => {
      console.log('[BackgroundFetch HeadlessTask] start');
      let response = await fetch('http://431c21b5.ngrok.io/');
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      console.log('[BackgroundFetch HeadlessTask] response: ', responseJson);
      BackgroundFetch.finish(BackgroundFetch.FETCH_RESULT_NEW_DATA);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("[js] RNBackgroundFetch failed to start");
    });

    // Optional: Query the authorization status.
    BackgroundFetch.status((status) => {
      switch(status) {
        case BackgroundFetch.STATUS_RESTRICTED:
          console.log("BackgroundFetch restricted");
          break;
        case BackgroundFetch.STATUS_DENIED:
          console.log("BackgroundFetch denied");
          break;
        case BackgroundFetch.STATUS_AVAILABLE:
          console.log("BackgroundFetch is enabled");
          break;
      }
    });
  }
```

Job is supposed to run when app is in background or closed,
Headless job is getting killed after i close the app,

Answer (score 0):

you need to put inside your index.js file your headlessTask

https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch#config-boolean-enableheadless-false